# Is there any implemented SubscribableChannel/EventDrivenConsumer out there to be used in a Spring Integration Kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration

All I have found so far are PollableChannel/PollableConsumer implementations, e.g.:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/kafka
Do I still need to keep searching?
Does it make sense at all an event driven channel for a Kafka consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [spring-integration-kafka Chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#si-channels) in the Spring for Apache Kafka Documentation.

> Spring Integration Kafka is now based on the Spring for Apache Kafka project. It provides the following components:
>
> Outbound Channel Adapter
>
> Message-driven Channel Adapter
>
> Inbound Channel Adapter
>
> Outbound Gateway
>
> Inbound Gateway
>
> Channels Backed by Kafka Topics

Comment: Thank you very much.